# MSBuild C# API 12.0

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

Is there a corresponding MSBuild C# API for the newly released MSBuild 12.0 which ships with Visual Studio 2013. I'm having a range of compatibility issues when using the 4.0 MSBuild assemblies.

I can see from executing a build using the API it will run the following executable:
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"

However the new executable shipped with VS 2013 is:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 12.0 Assemblies can be found in the following directory:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin"
```